# Сортировка таблицы в Pandas и инверсия таблицы

Tags: python, pandas

Загружаю таблицу данных, которая отсортирована по компаниям. На каждую компанию ряд данных. Какой функцией в Pandas можно отсортировать по дате от более старых дат к новым? И как полностью перевернуть таблицу, чтоб нижние строки стали верхними: просто построчно вверх ногами перевернуть всю таблицу?

```
import pandas as pd
stockQuotes = pd.read_json (r'D:\NeuroNet\DataBase\TimeSeriesPD.json')
stockQuotes = stockQuotes \
    .rename(columns = {0: 'Company', 1: 'DataTime', 2: 'Price'})
```

[image: цы P]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто сортировка по убыванию по двум колонкам:

```
stockQuotes = stockQuotes.sort_values(by=['DataTime', 'Company'], ascending=False)
```

Сортировка всей таблицы в обратном порядке:

```
stockQuotes.reindex(index=stockQuotes.index[::-1])
```

Только, все-таки, не `DataTime`, а `DateTime`.